# Javascript alert on pressing certain keyboard keys with certain sequence?

Tags: javascript

For example, when the user types "Hello" on his keyboard while he is on the homepage, a Javascript alert happens. 
I need this to implement some kind of easter egg into my website using Javascript.
Something like the Konami eastern egg of Facebook back in 2009

Comment: Where does the user type? In some text box? What have you tried?

Comment: you can use body key press

Comment: do you want to create shortcut keys?

Comment: yes some kind of shortcut keys but with certain sequence, so the event happens when the user types: H, E, L, L, O
something like the Konami eastern egg of facebook back in 2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic example of how it could be done with a help of jQuery:

```
var hello = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111].join();

$(window).on('keypress', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        gap = e.timeStamp - ($this.data('time') || e.timeStamp),
        chars = $this.data('chars') || [];

    if (gap > 1000) {
        chars = [];
    }

    chars.push(e.which);
    if (chars.join() === hello) {
        alert('Hello ;)');
    }

    $this.data('chars', chars);
    $this.data('time', e.timeStamp);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/TB9LK/1/

Comment: I tried to type: hello on my keyboard, but nothing really happened, I've also tried to change the char codes to 72, 69, 76, 76, 79 because I think there are the correct codes for hello, but nothing happened too

Comment: @AhmedElmasry `Hello` from the capital letter. `72` stands for the capital `H`.

Answer (score 2):

***An improvement:***

```
var seq = "rainbow"
var input = ""
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    input += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)

    for (var i = 0; i < seq.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] != seq[i] && input[i] != undefined) {
            input = ""
        }
    }

    if (input == seq) {
        alert("EASTER EGG!")

        input = ""
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you.
       $("body").on("keypress", function (e) {
      // logic for key event here
      });

Answer (score 0):

### A solution in pure JavaScript (no jQuery needed)

When the the sequence of keys "hello" are typed and alert is displayed.
Here's a working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcamcam/29rugq56/32/).

```
let stringVal="";
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  console.log(e.keyCode); // use this to debug the key codes
  switch(e.keyCode){
    case 104: // key code for h
      stringVal+="h";
      break;
    case 101: // key code for e
      stringVal+="e";
      break;
    case 108: // key code for l
      stringVal+="l";
      break;
    case 108: // key code for l
      stringVal+="l";
      break;
    case 111: // key code for o
      stringVal+="o";
      break;            
    default:
      stringVal=""; // this step is important to reset the value when any other key is pressed
  }
  /* if the keys 'hello' are pressed consecutively */
  if(stringVal.indexOf("hello")!=-1)
        alert('');
}
```